# Proving an inequality using AM-GM

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $ a,b,c > 0$ such that $ abc = 1$. Prove that 
>   $$\frac {ab}{a^2 + b^2 + \sqrt {c}} + \frac {bc}{b^2 + c^2 + \sqrt {a}} + \frac {ca}{c^2 + a^2 + \sqrt {b}}\le 1.$$

$$\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\sqrt{c^3}}$$

(AM-GM): $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\sqrt{c^3}\geq 3\sqrt{c} $$

$$\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\sqrt{c^3}}\leq \frac{1}{3\sqrt{c}}$$

Analogous: $$\frac{1}{\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\sqrt{a^3}} \leq \frac{1}{3\sqrt a}$$

$$\frac{1}{\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\sqrt{b^3}}\leq \frac{1}{3\sqrt b}$$

$$LHS \leq \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3} =1$$

Am I right?

Comment: You're proving that your sum is less that $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{3\sqrt{a}}$. This isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: How do you get that $\frac 1{3\sqrt a} + \frac 1{3\sqrt b} + \frac 1{3\sqrt c} \le \frac 13 +\frac 13 + \frac 13$?

Comment: The answer you accept uses also Cauchy Shwarz inequality. You wanted only Am-Gm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2+\sqrt{c}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{2ab+\sqrt{c^2ab}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{2\sqrt{ab}+c}=$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{2\sqrt{ab}+c}\right)=\frac{3}{2}-\sum_{cyc}\frac{c}{2(2\sqrt{ab}+c)}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{c}\right)^2}{2\sum\limits_{cyc}(2\sqrt{ab}+c)}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=1.$$

Comment: What do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easier way to prove the inequality. Just prove:

$$\frac {ab}{a^2 + b^2 + \sqrt {c}} \leq \frac {a+b}{2a + 2b + 2{c}} $$ and you are done! It is equivalent to $$a^2b+ab^2+2\leq a^3+b^3+ a\sqrt{c}+b\sqrt{c}$$ which is easy to see since $2\leq a\sqrt{c}+b\sqrt{c}$ and $ a^2b+ab^2\leq a^3+b^3$ are true by  Am-Gm inequality

---

**Edit to a comment.** I tried to find such a number $k$ that a following is true:
$$\frac {ab}{a^2 + b^2 + \sqrt {c}} \leq \frac {a^k+b^k}{2a^k + 2b^k + 2c^k} $$
Playing with $a,b,c$ (I put $a=b=x$ and $c=1/x^2$) a find that this is possible only at $k=1$. This is a method I saw when trying to solve: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17451p119168

Comment: $a^3+b^3-a^2b-ab^2=(a-b)^2(a+b)\geq 0$

Comment: This is nice. But, aside from the verification, where does the first inequality come from?

Comment: Thanks @Aqua. That is helpful.